# Entity Framework 4.1 Loose Coupling on Entities

Tags: c#, interface, entity-framework-4.1, data-annotations, loose-coupling

Need a little help please if anyone can shed some light on this.

I've created a code-first MVC 3 application which I have working fine.  I'm refactoring now to remove as much coupling as possible as I want the domain model to be used in various other MVC 3 applications later on.  What I have now is a collection of entities which are persisted via a normalised database and they are CRUD-ed through a repository pattern.  I have used Ninject to DI the repositories via the controller's constructor and am using models within the MVC 3 project to act as DAOs.

So, within the domain I have an entity called **Case** that has a foreign key to another case **Client** that looks like this:

```
public class Case : ICase
{
    [Key]
    public int CaseId { get; set; }
    public string CaseName { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public IClient Client { get; set; }
}
```

Then I have an interface (the interface exists mainly to implement it to the view model to add my data annotations - I know I could add the annotations to the domain object but as I said I want to use this domain model in other applications which will have a different ubiquitious language.

```
public interface ICase
{
    int CaseId { get; set; }
    string CaseName { get; set; }
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    IClient Client { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have my view model within the MVC 3 project.

```
public class CaseModel : ICase
{
    [HiddenInput(DisplayValue = false)]
    int CaseId { get; set; }

    [Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]
    [MaxLength(100)]
    string CaseName { get; set; }

    [RegularExpression("")]
    DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }    

    IClient Client { get; set; }    
}
```

So, my first problem is this: changing my foreign key reference for **Client** to **IClient** is a new thing, and it returns a null object.  When the type was a concrete class it returned fine - I assume this is because EF4.1 tries to create an instance of **IClient**.  Am I totally wrong here or is there a way around this?

My second problem (which may negate my first problem) is am I also doing something wrong by adding data annotations to a view model inheriting the interface of my domain entity?  Should I be using model meta data?  If so, how do I use meta data in such a way that I can make the data annotations unique to each project without touching the domain?

Thanks!

Comment: Just to clarify why the solution to the second problem may negate my first problem.  The only reason these interfaces exist is for the view models to have a structure similar to the domain entity.  If there is a better way of adding meta data for annotations to domain entities that reside in a different assembly, then these interfaces don't need to exist.  I can remove them and go back to using the concrete version of my domain entities.

Comment: You cannot use an interface for a navigation reference in your entity. It's like putting a `[NotMapped]` attribute on the property, EF simply ignores this property. You must have a concrete or abstract class. Only for collections you can use interfaces like `ICollection<T>`. `T` on the other hand must be a class again, not an interface. For standard collection interfaces EF has default rules how to instantiate them: `ICollection<T> -> HashSet<T>` or `IList<T> -> List<T>`, etc. For your custom defined interfaces, EF does not have such rules and doesn't know how to instantiate those.

Comment: Incidentally EF's now up to 4.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caveat: I'm not an expert on EF or MVC3.

We're in the process of building EF Code First entities, and we're not planning on adding interfaces to the entities. Repositories get interfaces. Units of Work get interfaces. Entities don't. Repositories return concrete entities, which are POCOs. Entities may be coupled to related entities. Models and other classes will typically get repository interfaces and/or unit of work interfaces injected in. For testing, we'll just new up some POCO entities and return them from the mock repositories.

We're planning to make the relevant POCO properties virtual so that EF can create proxies.

If you want to decouple a view from concrete entities, I'd first ask what value you expect to gain from that. Is the view going to be reused with different entities? If so, one option would be to use something like [AutoMapper](http://automapper.org/) to copy the properties over. You'd have to be aware of the immediate access of lazy-load properties, though.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply!  What I tried to convey in my original message was that the interfaces for the entities exist ONLY for the purpose of having like-wise structured view models (of which I add my application specified data annotations to).  The entity interfaces aren't there for de-coupling purposes at all.  I guess in saying that, my first problem is basically a mistake on my part.  What my actual question would be then, is how do I make my data annotations for the domain entity (for CRUD stuff) application specified and not hard-code it into the domain?

Comment: So you're saying you don't want to put the MVC HiddenInputAttribute on the entity, correct? I'd agree with that. I'd leave them on the ViewModel. Copy your entity over to your ViewModel (by hand or with AutoMapper), or just have your ViewModel delegate to the entity (which might be better). Again, I'm not an expert on the pattern - the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel) appears to use delegation.

Comment: And if you mean EF-specific attributes like MaxLength, I'd either say "so what - if we drop EF we've got other problems" or use the Fluent API to configure the mappings in a different class.

Comment: I did start to copy the properties of my domain entity to the view model by hand - but then stopped as I thought there must be a better way to do this.  I'll look into AutoMapper, haven't used that yet.  Are you aware of any way to define a metadata class within the MVC project and somehow bind it to the domain entity in that current context?

Comment: You mean apply attributes after-the-fact to a class? I am not aware of a way to do that, short of writing a wrapper class.

Comment: I'm pretty sure to get to where I want to be I'm going to have to use your earlier suggestion of manually copying the properties of my domain object to the view model in the project.  This way I can at least keep my data annotations separate from my domain, any view models that exist as POST models will use AutoMapper to synchronise the properties.